# Find duplicated row in SQL using Cursor

Tags: sql, plsql

I am using this loop to update the value one row at time. How do I exit the for loop once it comes across a duplicated value and prints out the duplicated row? 
The three keys are cust_ref, filter_name, and filter_type.

```
DECLARE

CURSOR c1
IS
  SELECT cust_ref, filter_name, cust_type
  FROM CUSTOMER
  WHERE cust_ref like 'CUST_REF%';

BEGIN

   FOR e in c1

   LOOP

    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET cust_ref = REPLACE (cust_ref, 'CUST_REF', 'UNDER_CUST_REF')
    WHERE cust_ref = e.cust_ref
          and filter_name = e.filter_name
          and cust_type = e.cust_type;  

   END LOOP;

END;
```

EDIT: I'm recieving this error when doing a regular update statement even when I drop or disable the primary key constraint.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.PRIMARYKEY) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Comment: very rarely should you need to write a loop in SQL. why not do this as a smarter UPDATE statement, and write a SELECT to find the duplicates?

Comment: I have used a SELECT and have tried using an UPDATE on its own but oracle is still complaining about a duplicate. So now I would like to iterate row by row to find exsactly where the duplicate is.

Answer (score 1):

This should show your duplicates, don't use a cursor

```
SELECT Second.cust_ref, Second.filter_name, Second.cust_type
  FROM CUSTOMER First
  JOIN CUSTOMER Second 
  ON First.cust_ref = REPLACE (Second.cust_ref, 'CUST_REF', 'UNDER_CUST_REF')
  WHERE First.cust_ref like '%CUST_REF%'
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not output any results.

Comment: What is the primary key on this table?

Comment: There is a primary key contraint with the three keys mentioned

Comment: In which case you probably have a key that doesn't begin with CUST_REF, see edited query

Comment: You're correct! There are some keys that already have UNDER_CUST_REF values so when I replace with my original UPDATE statement these are causing the duplicates. Now I need to figure out how to modify the UPDATE so it avoids trying to replace the already existing ones.